# How will I know that thread has completed its task?

Tags: windows, winapi, operating-system

Say for an example:-

I have created thread `pThread` using `CreateThread` Api which will perform some task say `vSampleTask`

How will i know that **pThread** has completed its task?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `GetExitCodeThread` to ask for the status of the thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understood this. I have one more doubt that after completion of task and after checking using "GetExitCodeThread" that thread has completed its task. Do i need to call ExitThread Api to end the thread or it is done automatically?

Comment: Type "GetExitCodeThread" into your Google searchbar, click on the first non-ad link and lookup the specification from MS itself. There you will find more complete answers.

Comment: So then in which circumstances programmer will use ExitThread Api? Is ExitThread used when programmer forcibly want to end the thread?

Comment: Exactly. You can think of it as a `break` in threads instead of loops.

Comment: The thread terminates itself in one of two ways. Call `ExitThread` passing the exit code. Or `return` the exit code from the thread procedure. `ExitThread` is useful when the thread procedure calls other procedures. A.H.'s analogy with `break` is excellent.

Answer (score 4):

You can wait on the thread handle with [`WaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx) or one of the other wait functions. You can use [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242.aspx) to allow your wait to be interrupted by input messages, for example. The thread handle becomes signaled when the thread's execution has completed.

As an alternative, you can check on a thread's status by calling [`GetExitCodeThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683190.aspx). This will return `FALSE` if the thread is still busy, and `TRUE` if it has completed. If the thread has completed, then the exit code will also be returned.

If one thread needs to wait for another to be complete then you should use the wait functions rather than a busy polling loop calling `GetExitCodeThread`. Busy loops and polling will just consume needless amounts of CPU (and power). Wait functions allow the waiting thread to become idle.

Comment: Thanks David for your response :)